# Executing MySql stored proc in Crontab

Tags: cron, mysql

I have a MySQL stored proc named "item" and I want `Cron` to run it for me - in server of course. I'm avoiding using MySQL events to unify all my 'jobs' - backup,etc.

Any how this is what I did in my `crontab` after I did `nano /etc/crontab`

`# m h dom mon dow user command`            **<=== My crontab fromat**
`00 12 * * * root mysql -e 'Call Item()'`    **<====but this doesn't work**

P.S Did the service cron restart.

Any idea how?

Comment: I tend to answer "No" to your question, although it might be "Yes", I just don't know because it is unclear what you want to know. How would either of those answer help you. Please update your post with a question like "How can I ...", which would make better clear what you want to do, and for which the  answer would actually help you more than Yes/No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax should be like this in the `crontab` file

`crontab -e`  will edit the file you don't need `nano`

`00 12 * * * sh /path/to/yourfile.sh`

If you want to run it from `MySQL` user then you need to `su mysql` and do the same thing mentioned above

Comment: Got it. But how do I exactly find the location of an MySQL stored procedure? Unlike sh files where you can find the exact location.

Comment: unable to understand, which location are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I read your unedited post. Nevermind that. Can you specify this for me: "If you want to run it from MySQL user then you need to su mysql and do the same thing mentioned above"

Comment: try this and check if fulfill your requirement.

Comment: `00 12 * * * sh /var/lib/mysql ` **<== location of my databases.**  Where exactly do I "Call Item()" **to invoke my stored proc**

Comment: where is the script? you have to mention the path of the script.

Comment: If he script is save in `/var/lib/mysql` then it should be written like this `/var/lib/mysql/scriptname` it will get executed

Comment: I was thinking on executing the MySQL stored procedure directly - `item()` and not put it in some sh or text file. Is there no way to do that directly?

Comment: e.g `00 12 * * * mysql "update account set name = 'me'"` but instead of the query I put `item()` **my stored proc**

Comment: Is it working now, what is the our come. Try to run it from the command line first then try `crontab`.

Comment: Did this: `00 12 * * * mysql -pMYPASS DB_NAME -e 'Call Item();` But cron doesn't execute. Is there something missing? P.S The time I used is now. MySql command works and did service cron restart.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems got a delay. It did the job. Thanks man. I guess what I did only wrong was the nano /etc/crontab. Thank @avinash Redy